# Singleton class for database mysqli phpversion 5.2.17

Tags: php, class, oop, mysqli, singleton

I was having some issues building a singleton class for a mysqli object to be used by more than one class. I originally got the error `Access to undeclared static property: database::$DBH` which I don't understand as the property is not static. I presumed it might of been because `phpversion()` returned 5.2.17 and I discovered the singleton pattern could only be done using version >5.3? (Could be completely wrong). I looked into it and found that my server provider, allows me to chose the version of PHP that I can use. I've currently selected 5.3.3 but again, same error. Either I've got to wait for the server to 'refresh' it's settings. Or I do have a legitimate error with the version 5.3.3

```
class database{
    private$DBH;
    private static$singleton;
    protected function __construct(){
        $this->$DBH=new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
        //also tried self::$DBH;
        //if(mysqli_connect_errno())print_r(mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    public static function instance(){
        if(!(self::$singleton instanceof self))self::$singleton=new self();
        return self::$singleton;
    }
    public static function get(){
        return self::instance()->$DBH;
    }
    private function __wake(){}
    private function __clone(){}
}
class test{
    public function __construct(){
        $get=database::get()->prepare('SELECT column FROM table');
        $get->execute();
        $get->bind_result($col);
        while($get->fetch()){
            print($col."\n");
        }
        //$get->close(); not required.
    }
}
$t=new test();
```

IS there any alternatives to want I'm trying to achieve? (singular mysqli object to be used with multiple classes, also what a 'securer' method from a standard object.)

Should I extend my database class with mysqli?

Should I just use PDO?

OR again better still! Get a better server provider where their services are up to date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not make it overcomplicated, just extend `MySQLi` class, add some methods to it. `MySQLi` is already a connector itself, why store another connector inside a connector?

```
class Database extends MySQLi {
     private static $instance = null ;

     private function __construct($host, $user, $password, $database){ 
         parent::__construct($host, $user, $password, $database);
     }

     public static function getInstance(){
         if (self::$instance == null){
             self::$instance = new self(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
         }
         return self::$instance ;
     }
}

$db = Database::getInstance();
$result = $db->query("SELECT 1 FROM table");
```

A few tips:

- `Non-static` properties are accessed via `$object->property`
- `Static` properties are accessed via: `self::$property` or `Database::$property` or `static::$property`
- use of `PDO` is really good since you can bind values, thus securing your database from injections. As an option - extend `PDO` class.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for long reply, exactly what I was trying to achieve. I noticed you didn't include 'function' within your script. Why was that?

Comment: Unfortunatelly you cannot make singleton class from class extending mysqli (or PDO) because real singleton requires making constructor method private (in order not to able to instantiate singleton), on the other hand mysqli constructor is public and you cannot override public method with private one. If you try to override mysqli's public constructor with private one in your inherited (singleton) class PHP will return Fatal Error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `$` from `$DBH` in `$this->$DBH=new mysqli` and in `return self::instance()->$DBH;` since you're already referring to its current object with `$this->DBH`

```
class database{
    private $DBH;
    private static $singleton;
    protected function __construct(){
        $this->DBH=new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
        //also tried self::$DBH;
        //if(mysqli_connect_errno())print_r(mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    public static function instance(){
        if(!(self::$singleton instanceof self)) self::$singleton=new self();
        return self::$singleton;
    }
    public static function get(){
        return self::instance()->DBH;
    }
    private function __wake(){}
    private function __clone(){}
}
class test{
    public function __construct(){
        $get=database::get()->prepare('SELECT column FROM table');
        $get->execute();
        $get->bind_result($col);
        while($get->fetch()){
            print($col."\n");
        }
        //$get->close(); not required.
    }
}
$t=new test();
```